# ViewHolder not showing data

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to sort the posts according to the timestamp of the posts.The posts contains title and description.I am using firebase to retrieve data. But nothing shows up in the viewholder. The viewholder is blank. IS there anything i am doing wrong?

```
public class AlertsActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    public static class BlogViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        View mview;
        public BlogViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            mview = itemView;
        }

        public void setTitle(String title) {
            TextView post_title = (TextView)mview.findViewById(R.id.blog_title);
            post_title.setText(title);

        }

        public void setDesp(String desp) {
            TextView post_desp = (TextView) mview.findViewById(R.id.blog_desp);
            post_desp.setText(desp);
        }


        public void setTimestampCreated(HashMap<String, Object> timestamp) {
            TextView show_ts = (TextView) mview.findViewById(blog_timestamp);
            show_ts.setText(String.valueOf(timestamp));
        }
    }
```

Adapter:

```
      mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Blog");
      mDatabase.keepSynced(true);
      mDatabase.orderByChild("timestamp");        

      FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Blog, BlogViewHolder> firebaseRecyclerAdapter = new
            FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Blog, BlogViewHolder>(
                    Blog.class,
                    R.layout.blog_row,
                    BlogViewHolder.class, mDatabase) {
                @Override
                protected void populateViewHolder(final BlogViewHolder viewHolder, final Blog model, int position) {
                    mDatabase.child("Blog").orderByChild("timestamp").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                            String alerts = dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);
                            HashMap<String, Object> time = (HashMap<String, Object>) dataSnapshot.getValue();
                            viewHolder.setTitle(alerts);
                            viewHolder.setDesp(alerts);
                            viewHolder.setTimestampCreated(time);
                        }


                        @Override
                        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                        }
                    });
                }
            };
    mbloglist.setAdapter(firebaseRecyclerAdapter);
    }
```

Image of the database:
  https://i.stack.imgur.com/GNouK.png

Comment: *IS there anything i am doing wrong?* **question is: is there anything that you are do it right** ... you are creating adapter inside onProgressUpdate of async task which is never used, your code is not formated , and cleary is not complete

Comment: @Selvin I am using async task so that the progress bar shows up. and yes i have showed only the important part which is needed. This is not the complete code

Comment: *I have showed only the important part which is needed* and doesn't makes sens

Comment: @Selvin Now does it make sense?

Comment: @MadhuBanerjee: you're attaching a listener inside your `populateViewHolder`. While this may be necessary, it is uncommon and leads to lots of potential edge-cases. Can you show a snippet of the JSON you are trying to show? You can get this by clicking the "Export JSON" link in your [Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data).

Comment: As a first mistake: `mDatabase.orderByChild("timestamp");` does nothing right now. You need to capture the resulting in a variable and use that: `Query sortedPosts = mDatabase.orderByChild("timestamp");` and then pass that into the adapter.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I have provided with the link of the database image above in the question. Thank you

Comment: @MadhuBanerjee no screenshots of text please. Instead get the actual JSON from the console, by clicking on the overflow menu (the vertical line of three dots) and then "Export JSON".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code looks way too complex for such a simple structure. The main purpose of using the adapter from FirebaseUI, is so that you don't have to deal with listeners yourself. As far as I can see you just need:

```
mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Blog");
Query orderedBlogs = mDatabase.orderByChild("timestamp");        

FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Blog, BlogViewHolder> firebaseRecyclerAdapter = new
        FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Blog, BlogViewHolder>(
                Blog.class,
                R.layout.blog_row,
                BlogViewHolder.class, orderedBlogs) {
    @Override
    protected void populateViewHolder(BlogViewHolder viewHolder, Blog model, int position) {
        viewHolder.setTitle(blog.title);
        viewHolder.setDesp(blog.desp);
        viewHolder.setTimestampCreated(blog.timestamp);
    }
};
mbloglist.setAdapter(firebaseRecyclerAdapter);
```

This is the corresponding minimal `Blog` class:

```
public class Blog {
  public String desp;
  public long timestamp;
  public string title;
}
```

Comment: Its still the same though! After days of searching and trying all the combination I had to use: LinearLayoutManager mLayoutManager=new LinearLayoutManager(AlertsActivity.this);
            mLayoutManager.setReverseLayout(true);
           mLayoutManager.setStackFromEnd(true); It is not working out using orderbychild() for some reason!

Comment: That code just reverses the layout. It should make no difference in whether items show up, which is what your initial post says doesn't happen.

Comment: Oh! just forgot to mention that the items are showing up after i tried your code. I was talking about the data not being in sorted order even after using orderbychild(). So i had to use the reverse layout thing. My bad! @Frank van Puffelen